# Index number is misplaced in table

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

like if I click on first cell it shows me index no 3, If again I click on it it shows me some other index number

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier = "CELL"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell

    cell.nameLabel!.text     = restaurantNames[indexPath.row]
    cell.locationLabel!.text = restaurantLocations[indexPath.row]
    cell.typeLabel!.text     = restaurantTypes[indexPath.row]

    cell.thumbnailImageView!.image = UIImage(named:resturantImages[indexPath.row])
    cell.thumbnailImageView!.layer.cornerRadius = cell.thumbnailImageView.frame.size.width  / 2
    cell.thumbnailImageView!.clipsToBounds = true

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Mention your didselectrowatindexpath delegate method as well. Because that is the one delegate which gets called on that event.

Comment: show me your didSelectRowAtIndexPath method

Comment: Check all the tableview delegate methods that are implemented in your class. Might be, somewhere the index returned is malformed. Also, have you mistakenly implemented didDeselectRowAtIndexPath delegate method?